# Change colour of clicked edge in Three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, raycasting

```
var egh = new THREE.EdgesHelper(cube, 0xff0000);
egh.material.linewidth = 5;
scene.add(egh);
```

I have created cube using

```
new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200, 1, 1, 1, materials), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
```

where opacity is set to 0 and only edges are visible. Now if I click on any edge its colour should change. I am getting face from Raycaster.intersectObjects but not able to find clicked edge. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

when raycasting onto THREE.Line you should set raycasters parameter

```
raycaster.linePrecision
```

to a value higher than the default 1 as only lines that have distance from the ray lower than that value will be returned (essentially this sets the "thickness" of the lines for raycaster)

you should also take note that this will make lines "grow" both inside and outside of the object, so matching the points of the closest face with the intersected lines is a good idea even for simple object as a cube

another way would be calculating distance of the face intersect to each line and the closest one will be the correct edge - this looks easier and more robust than using a raycaster when you already have the intersect point

```
var intersectPoint = raycastresult[0].point;
var line = new THREE.Line3();
var positions = edges.geometry.getAttribute("position").array
for(var i = 0; i < positions.length;i+=2)
{
    line.start.fromArray(positions,i*3);
    line.end.fromArray(positions,i*3+3);
    var closestPoint = line.closestPointToPoint(intersectPoint);
    distance = closestPoint.distanceTo(intersectPoint);
    if(distance < minDistance)
    {
        minDistance = distance;
        closestEdgeIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting line as undefined.

Comment: there was a missing "new" keyword, but the code is untested, it should serve like a guideline more than a solution